# Changing a JS Class to be able to call it multiple times

Tags: javascript, class

This is an example of a JS Class :

```
function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

var Canvasfun = function (x) {
    function Canvasfun(x) {
        _classCallCheck(this, Canvasfun);

        this.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        this.dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
        this.ctx.scale(this.dpr, this.dpr);

        this.render = this.render.bind(this);

        this.funnythingy(x);
        this.listener(x);

        this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth * this.dpr;
        this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight * this.dpr;
        this.canvas.style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px';
        this.canvas.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
    }

    Canvasfun.prototype.funnythingy = function funnythingy( x) {
        //do stuff
    };

    Canvasfun.prototype.listener = function listener() {
        // Use TweenLite tick event for the render loop
        TweenLite.ticker.addEventListener('tick', this.render);
    };

    Canvasfun.prototype.finalfunnythingy = function finalfunnythingy() {
        //do stuff
    };

    Canvasfun.prototype.render = function render() {
        this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
        this.finalfunnythingy();
    };

    return Canvasfun;
}();
```

The Canvasfun function gets the environment variables, then calls other function within the Class.
Then the other functions just do some stuff on the canvas, and they are inter linked depending on their actions.

This is is simplified for the purpose of the question, and to remain generic.

The question is :

How to call this function multiple times ? 
When I do it once :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var funnyaction = new Canvasfun(10);
 });
```

it works, but if I do it twice :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var funnyaction = new Canvasfun(10);
var funnyaction2 = new Canvasfun(30);
 });
```

then only the second one is visible in the canvas (if I put an alert(), it pops twice).

---

**EDIT :**

Here is a more complete code, in case it could help. I'd like to understand how Canvas and Class work with multiple instance, or how to adapt it for that purpose.

I execute it with :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var funnyaction = new ConfettiCannon(10,20,30,40);
var funnyaction2 = new ConfettiCannon(30,25,10,60);
 });
```

I try to understand what happens with alerts.
I see a first alert with the x0,y0,x1,y1
then a second alert with the velocity
then the id=1,2,3,4,

followed immediately by another alert with x0,y0,x1,y1 (for the second instance)
then second velocty
but then, instead of having again, id=1,2,3,4, I have this time id 5,6,7,8

and THEN, I see the effect on the canvas.

```
function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

var ConfettiCannon = function (x0, y0, x1, y1) {
    function ConfettiCannon(x0, y0, x1, y1) {
        _classCallCheck(this, ConfettiCannon);

        // setup a canvas
        this.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        this.dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
        this.ctx.scale(this.dpr, this.dpr);

        // add confetti here
        this.confettiSpriteIds = [];
        this.confettiSprites = {};

        // bind methods
        this.render = this.render.bind(this);
        // this.handleMouseup = this.handleMouseup.bind(this);

        this.setupListeners();
        this.handleMouseup(x0, y0, x1, y1);

        this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth * this.dpr;
        this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight * this.dpr;
        this.canvas.style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px';
        this.canvas.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';

        // fire off for a demo
        //this.timer = setTimeout(this.handleMouseup, 2000);
    }

    ConfettiCannon.prototype.setupListeners = function setupListeners() {
        // Use TweenLite tick event for the render loop
        TweenLite.ticker.addEventListener('tick', this.render);
    };

    ConfettiCannon.prototype.handleMouseup = function handleMouseup( x0, y0, x1, y1) {

        alert(x0+ '-'+y0+'-'+x1+'-'+y1);
        var x = x1 - x0;
        var y = y1 - y0;
        var length = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        var y2 = y1 - y0;
        var x2 = x1 - x0;
        var angle = Math.atan2(y2, x2) * (180 / Math.PI) + 180;

        var particles = length / 5 + 80; // +5
        var velocity = length * 20; // *10
        this.addConfettiParticles(particles, angle, velocity, x0, y0);
    };

    ConfettiCannon.prototype.addConfettiParticles = function addConfettiParticles(amount, angle, velocity, x, y) {
        var i = 0;
        alert(velocity);
        //while (i < amount) {
        while (i < 4) {
            var _sprite;

            // sprite
            var r = _.random(4, 6) * this.dpr;
            var d = _.random(15, 25) * this.dpr;

            var colorArray = [
                'rgb(151, 56, 245)',
                'rgb(0, 255, 165)'
            ];
            var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*colorArray.length);
            var color = colorArray[randomNumber];

            var tilt = _.random(10, -10);
            var tiltAngleIncremental = _.random(0.07, 0.05);
            var tiltAngle = 0;

            var id = _.uniqueId();
            var sprite = (_sprite = {}, _sprite[id] = {
                angle: angle,
                velocity: velocity,
                x: x,
                y: y,
                r: r,
                d: d,
                color: color,
                tilt: tilt,
                tiltAngleIncremental: tiltAngleIncremental,
                tiltAngle: tiltAngle
            }, _sprite);

            Object.assign(this.confettiSprites, sprite);
            this.confettiSpriteIds.push(id);
            this.tweenConfettiParticle(id);
            i++;
        }
    };

    ConfettiCannon.prototype.tweenConfettiParticle = function tweenConfettiParticle(id) {
        var _this = this;

        alert(id);
        var minAngle = this.confettiSprites[id].angle - 60 / 2;
        var maxAngle = this.confettiSprites[id].angle + 60 / 2;

        var minVelocity = this.confettiSprites[id].velocity / 4;
        var maxVelocity = this.confettiSprites[id].velocity;

        // Physics Props
        var velocity = _.random(minVelocity, maxVelocity);
        var angle = _.random(minAngle, maxAngle);
        var gravity = 1200;
        var friction = _.random(0.1, 0.25);
        var d = 0;

        TweenLite.to(this.confettiSprites[id], 4, {
            physics2D: {
                velocity: velocity,
                angle: angle,
                gravity: gravity,
                friction: friction
            },
            d: d,
            ease: Power4.easeIn,
            onComplete: function onComplete() {
                // remove confetti sprite and id
                _.pull(_this.confettiSpriteIds, id);
                delete _this.confettiSprites[id];
            }
        });
    };

    ConfettiCannon.prototype.drawConfetti = function drawConfetti() {
        var _this2 = this;

        this.confettiSpriteIds.map(function (id) {
            var sprite = _this2.confettiSprites[id];

            _this2.ctx.beginPath();
            _this2.ctx.lineWidth = sprite.d / 2;
            _this2.ctx.strokeStyle = sprite.color;
            _this2.ctx.moveTo(sprite.x + sprite.tilt + sprite.r, sprite.y);
            _this2.ctx.lineTo(sprite.x + sprite.tilt, sprite.y + sprite.tilt + sprite.r);
            _this2.ctx.stroke();

            _this2.updateConfettiParticle(id);
        });
    };

    ConfettiCannon.prototype.updateConfettiParticle = function updateConfettiParticle(id) {
        var sprite = this.confettiSprites[id];

        var tiltAngle = 0.0005 * sprite.d;

        sprite.angle += 0.01;
        sprite.tiltAngle += tiltAngle;
        sprite.tiltAngle += sprite.tiltAngleIncremental;
        sprite.tilt = Math.sin(sprite.tiltAngle - sprite.r / 2) * sprite.r * 2;
        sprite.y += Math.sin(sprite.angle + sprite.r / 2) * 2;
        sprite.x += Math.cos(sprite.angle) / 2;
    };


    ConfettiCannon.prototype.render = function render() {
        this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

        this.drawConfetti();
    };

    return ConfettiCannon;
}();
```

Comment: final answer bellow by mherzig (i.e. adding an Id for the canvas, and changing the html/css to have both canvas on top of each other)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to make much sense of your example, but one thing that I can see is that in your constructor, every instance of `Canvasfun` will use the exact same canvas (`id` of `canvas`). Then in your render method you clear the canvas, which means each instantiation of `Canvasfun` will wipe the common canvas and draw only it's own paths.

Comment: I added more code + more info on what appears on page load (the alerts results), I have indeed something going on with ids, instead of two sets of 1,2,3,4, I have 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8. Any idea of how to transform such Class into one that can be triggered multiple times ?

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no issue with this being triggered multiple times. The sprite IDs don't start from 1 each time because you are using a global library (underscore) to get a unique ID each time. Underscore has no idea, nor does it care, about the context in which you are calling it. I still believe your issue is that you erase the canvas before each draw, so for each "tick" the last instance will always win.

Comment: Try this: have two `<canvas>` elements on your page, one with an `id` of "canvas" and the other of "canvas1" and then make the canvas your class uses be a fifth param passed into the class, as in `this.canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);`. I'm guessing that if you can see both canvases side-by-side it will be obvious that they are both working.

Comment: I see, so I would need to either find a way to give an id to the canvas, or to not clear it in render function ? I tried removing the "this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);" line, and it does the opposite, i.e. leaving every small particles that are drawn in the canvas, leaving a trail instead of refreshing the canvas like frames. 
With two canvas, this time, only the first effect is visible.

Comment: You do need to call `clearRect()` in your case because you don't want the trails. So I see two options: one is (assuming you will only have a few of these instantiated at once) to have your class create a new `<canvas>` itself, append that into some containing `<div>`, and it draws to it's own canvas and they are all just stacked on top of each other. Other option is to actually only have this run as a single instance, and then that one instance keeps track of *all* confettis and redraws them all on every tick.

Comment: I like the first option, will give it a try ! I am not very familiar with Canvas, and tick, and Physics, so the logic of Classes seems different from PHP for example ! 

but before I try it, with the two canvas and canvasId option, when I remove all CSS code, I see them both on the page. so when they are overlayed, it seems one is hidding the other. I thought Canvas were transparent (background) !?

Comment: Yes, it should be transparent, unless somewhere else in your code you are filling it with a background color. Or maybe a buggy browser I suppose.

Comment: I ended up doing :

<div id="container">
<canvas class="canvas" id="canvas"></canvas>
<canvas class="canvas" id="canvas1"></canvas>
<canvas class="canvas" id="canvas2"></canvas>
<canvas class="canvas" id="canvas3"></canvas>
</div>


and in the css: 

    #container { position: relative; }
    .canvas { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }

works like a charm ! thank you